# Inconsistent variables from sh command and reading from file

Tags: python, git

I have a problem where a string gained using the sh module with git and a string written to a file do not match

I get the commit string as follows

```
from sh import stat, git
repo = git.bake(_cwd=git_dir)
current_commit=git.log("-n1", "--format='%T'", git_file)
```

current_commit shows as follows

```
print current_commit
'89a848eb9ea98bfd6770301dce848052ec8ef63f'
```

The type is as follows

```
type(current_commit)
<class 'sh.RunningCommand'>
```

I can change it to a string, it's length is 66

```
type(str(current_commit))
<type 'str'>
len(str(current_commit))
66
```

Which is different to the length of the actual string

```
len('89a848eb9ea98bfd6770301dce848052ec8ef63f')
40
```

The current_commit is written to a file as follows

```
with open(commit_store_file, 'w+') as f:
        f.write(str(current_commit))
```

When I open this file with vi I see the following

```
^[[?1h^[=^M'89a848eb9ea98bfd6770301dce848052ec8ef63f'^[[m
^M^[[K^[[?1l^[>
```

I read it back with the following

```
with open(commit_store_file, 'r+') as f:
    stored_commit = f.readline()
```

The type here is string

```
type(stored_commit)
<type 'str'>
```

The length is 55

```
print len(stored_commit)
55
```

How can I retrieve the actual string using sh and store it correctly so that they match?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not familiar with `sh` so I can't help with how to solve it, but it looks to me like your `str(current_commit)` is getting ansi color codes in it.  You can try telling the git command not to use color and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those characters look like pager stuff to me.

Try adding `--no-pager` to the front of the command:

```
    git --no-pager log -n 1 --format='%T' --color=never
```

The option needs to go before the `log` command, not after, so you'll have to `bake` it in. Another way to get the same effect would be to muck with the `GIT_PAGER` environment variables or the config settings.

A different way to get a machine-readable tree hash would be `git cat-file -p HEAD`. The tree will come out on the first line of the output, prefixed by "tree ".